# DB insert with laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using ajax to update the database when I drag/drop an element from a nested list. But The query is getting the parameter I pass AS column name.

Code inside my Model:

```
public static function atualiza_drag($disc, $professor, $old)
    {
        DB::insert('INSERT INTO disciplina_professor (disciplina_id, professor_id) VALUES (`$disc`, `$professor`)');        
        DB::delete("DELETE FROM disciplina_professor WHERE professor_id = `$old`");
    }
```

The Error:

> local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3' in 'field list'

`3` is the ID I got from ajax but instead of using this as parameter it's using as a column name and I cant find out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove grave accent (`) from the variables.

Here it should looks like

```
public static function atualiza_drag($disc, $professor, $old)
    {
        DB::insert('INSERT INTO disciplina_professor (disciplina_id, professor_id) VALUES ($disc, $professor)');        
        DB::delete('DELETE FROM disciplina_professor WHERE professor_id = $old');
    }
```

**Note:** If you use single quote (') in your insert then do also use single quote in your delete.

**Characters and symbols names** 
Single qoute = ' 
Grave accent = `

**Resources** 
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database 
http://www.lookuptables.com/ 
http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: Removed the Grave accent was right. But I cant use single quote, PHP won't parse that as a variable. But it seems to do the job. I'll test and be right back.